# Cause compiler error when enumeration and identifier list don't match in length

Tags: c

We have an enumeration in our system that looks like this:

```
enum EventCode {
    BAD_CONFIG = 0,
    BAD_NET = 1,
    ...
    BAD_UNKNOWN = 92,
    // This should always be at the end, and the numbers in
    // this list should be continuous!
    EVENT_LIST_LENGTH
}
```

And the corresponding event mode identifier list:

```
int eventModeType[] = {
    INT32,
    ...
    INT16 // List position 92.
}
```

At some point this was added:

```
enum EventCode {
    ...
    BAD_UNKNOWN = 92,
    NEW_ERROR = 100,
    // This should always be at the end, and the numbers in
    // this list should be continuous!
    EVENT_LIST_LENGTH
}
```

and even though the corresponding mode was added to `eventModeType`, this line obviously caused *Undefined Behaviour*:

```
// Oh no, EVENT_LIST_LENGTH is too large!!!
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < EVENT_LIST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    printf("Error code %d | %d\n", i, eventModeType[i]);
}
```

**How can i cause a compiler error when `EVENT_LIST_LENGTH` and the length of `eventModeType` don't match, so no-one can make this mistake?**

Comment: In the comments inside your enum it's said: "This should always be at the end, and _the numbers in this list should be continuous!_", so why are you setting all the values in the enum?  If you add only `NEW_ERROR,` you only have to add the corresponding mode and eventually check with a sizeof.

Comment: @Bob__ The comment is what i have just added to warn people about this. There are other reasons to do this as well, for eg. this list represents a events for a similar list also stored on the client side for deserializing these events. Having the numbers there explicitly makes it easier to see what is associated with what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to do this:

```
// macro to stop warning from unused variable.
#define _unused(x) ((void)x) 

// Actual size of list.
const int EVENT_MODE_LIST_LENGTH = sizeof(eventModeType) / sizeof(eventModeType[0]);

// With -Werror turned on, the following function will produce the error:
// error : size of array 'arr' is too large
// in the event that  EVENT_LIST_LENGTH is larger then EVENT_MODE_LIST_LENGTH 
void evantModeArraySizeChecker(void)
{
    int arr[EVENT_LIST_LENGTH - EVENT_MODE_LIST_LENGTH + 1];
    _unused(arr);
    int arr2[EVENT_MODE_LIST_LENGTH - EVENT_LIST_LENGTH + 1];
    _unused(arr2);
}
```

This will cause a compiler error if this list is modified incorrectly.

Comment: Modern C has `static_assert`that let's you check if a condition is fulfilled at compile time. No more need for weird array expressions that lead to incomprehensive compiler errors.

Comment: @JensGustedt  I assume you are referring to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/static_assert), and yeah that would be awesome, unfortunately our compiler does not support `C11`. You should add it as an answer though, i would upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just that the computation of the length of `evenModeType` array is wrong. Modern C provides you with a tool that even avoids tricks as `EVENT_LIST_LENGTH`. Just use designated initialisers:

```
int eventModeType[] = {
    [BAD_CONFIG] = INT32,
    ...
    [BAD_UNKNOWN] = INT16, // List position 92.
    [NEW_ERROR] = WnatEver, 
}
```

Otherwise if you just want to inhibit an out

Comment: So, in case of a "gap" in the events code the corresponding element is set to 0. How can this be checked before iterating through the array?

Comment: Why should this be checked? This will just print `0` in the example of the question. Code that uses this type of convention should be written to be robust for such cases, anyhow, and in particular know how to deal with the special value `0`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes you are right, but the question is a simplification of what is done, if we require the list to be continuous and without 0's for some reason (we don't in this case) then i don't think this solution would work.